# Old sci-fi novel where people live in domes controlled by aliens and only traders can move between them

Tags: story-identification, novel

The setting is a small village that lives under a dome (can't remember why but it's a pastoral setting, no tech).  Traders can move between domes as they have permission from aliens to do so.  Aliens have monitors that fly around like bees, only they are larger (maybe drone sized?).

The story begins with two children playing with a radio and a small (maybe a "baby") alien monitor wanders into the barn where they are fooling with it.  Somehow they damage it with the radio I think.

That's about where I ran out of time and had to return the book to the library over 20 years ago.

Comment: I don't know enough about the book to post an answer but could this be [_The White Mountains_](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/64316.The_White_Mountains) by John Christopher? It seems to match the general idea of what you're describing.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot:  That's what first came to my mind too, but in those novels the aliens live in the domes, and monitor humanity by traveling around in large tripods.

Comment: Thanks but I dont recall this being in first person.  I distinctly recall it starting off talking about a little boy and I think a girl playing with a forbidden radio.  But that book also seemed interesting so I am going to order a copy!